# Animate on Scroll: All Classes Not Triggering

Tags: javascript, css

I have a custom CSS animation that blurs and fades text that I'd like triggered once a user encounters the elements on the page. I've set up some JS that adds an animation class once specific elements are in view.

The problem I'm having is that I have two sets of elements that use the same animation class and the script I have is only triggering the first one:

```
      h1.blurry-text {
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 1;
      }

      span.blurry-text-fade {
        animation: blur 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-animation: blur 0.5s ease;
        animation-delay: 1s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }

      @keyframes blur {
        0% {
          color: transparent;
          text-shadow: 0 0 0px #1e1e1e;
        }
        50% {
          color: transparent;
          text-shadow: 0 0 5px #1e1e1e;
        }
        100% {
          color: transparent;
          text-shadow: 0 0 10px #1e1e1e;
          opacity: 0.3;
        }
      }
```

```
<h1 class="blurry-text">

    <span class="blurry-text-fade-hold">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</span><br />
    This is important
    <span class="blurry-text-fade-hold">Blah Blah<br />
    Blah Bla Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
    </span>

</h1>
```

```
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          const blurryText = entry.target.querySelector(
            ".blurry-text-fade-hold"
          );

          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            blurryText.classList.add("blurry-text-fade");
            return;
          }
        });
      });

      observer.observe(document.querySelector(".blurry-text"));
```

Basically, I'm trying to get all the text around "This is important" to use my animation once scrolled into view. The first `<span>` is activated, but the following one is not. I've tried changing `entry.target.querySelector` to `entry.target.querySelectorAll` but then I get an error that the classList is undefined.

[I made a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtx2db04/) in case that's easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

The `querySelectorAll` method returns a collection, then the class is set for for every item in the collection, like this:

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting)
      entry.target.querySelectorAll(
          ".blurry-text-fade-hold"
        ).forEach(blurryText => blurryText.classList.add("blurry-text-fade"));
      });
});
```